# Why do you DirectCast the HttpWebRequest in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, directcast

When using the POST method for an httpwebrequest, I often see a line of code like this:

```
Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://www.empireavenue.com/user/login/do"), HttpWebRequest)
```

Why do we do a DirectCast here? What is it exactly doing?

Edit: Or maybe my question is, Why do we call WebRequest.Create and cast it to an HttpWebRequest? What is going on here technically speaking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WebRequest.Create` is a factory method which can return different types of requests. Because of that all of them are returned typed as `WebRequest`. But because you may know, that you're expecting it to return `HttpWebRequest` (because Uri you've provided is http) you can downcast it to get access to methods and properties exposed by `HttpWebRequest`, which are not exposed by `WebRequest` base class.

But, you should probably use `WebRequest.CreateHttp()` instead of `WebRequest.Create()`, if you know you're going to use http protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Because [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) implements WebRequest and [WebRequest.Create()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc.aspx) returns a WebRequest object.

Comment: Looks like it does actually implicitly cast in .NET 4.5 http://dotnetfiddle.net/102lBR